# PHP Remove all but x from array

Tags: php, arrays

is there a sensible way of removing ALL fields from an array APART from ones that I specify?

I'm thinking something along the lines of `array_diff` could work, but I only want to list the field keys that I want to allow, and then say 'drop everything else'. What's the best way of doing that?

Many thanks

Comment: How would you specify these fields? In the code or dynamically?

Comment: Is this an array from a database result?

Comment: Why vote this question down? It doesn't matter what the array is or where it came from - it's just any given array, use your imagination like @PleaseStand has..!

Comment: If it comes from a database, then the "best" solution is to select only the columns you want from the database in the first place.... if it doesn't come from a db, then you need a PHP solution - so the source of the array does matter if you want a "best" solution... it only doesn't matter if you simply want something that works.... and I didn't vote down the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[array_intersect_key()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) should work if copying the array is OK.

```
$arr = array(
    'A' => 'alpha',
    'B' => 'bravo',
    'C' => 'charlie',
    'D' => 'delta'
);

$allowedKeys = array('B', 'C');

print_r(array_intersect_key($arr, array_flip($allowedKeys)));

# Array
# (
#    [B] => bravo
#    [C] => charlie
# )
```

Otherwise, you can use a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (!in_array($key, $allowedKeys)) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: That first example is awesome - exactly what I'm after. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.. That might work for you

```
foreach($array as $key=>&$value) {
        if($key!='yourx') {
            unset($array[$key])
        }
    }
```